# Click event on dynamic select list only works in FF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select list dynamically created with PHP. I also have a JQuery script that modifies the form based upon the users selection from the list, however the click event is only recognized in FF but not by Safari or Chrome (have not tried IE yet). I tried to get more specific with the JQ selector but that did not help. This is my first attempt at getting a website to work across all browsers so all help is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<select id="formcategory" name="Category">
  <option value="Select One">Select One</option>
  <option class="BloodSample" value="1">Blood Sample</option>
  <option class="Exercise" value="2">Exercise</option>
  <option class="InsulinInjection" value="3">Insulin Injection</option>
  <option class="Meal" value="4">Meal</option>
  <option class="Symptoms" value="5">Symptoms</option>
  <option class="UrineSample" value="6">Urine Sample</option>
</select>


PHP to create the select list:                  
<?php
  if(!$_POST) {
    echo "<option value='Select One'>Select One</option>";
    }
  else {
echo "<option value='".$_POST['Category']."'>".$_POST['Category']."</option>";
    }
    foreach($array1 as $key=>$val) {
  if($key<10) {
    echo "<option class='".(str_replace(" ","",$val))."'value='".$key."'>".$val. "</option>";
}
}

?>

JQ
$('#formcategory').on('click','option',function() {

    console.log($(this));//only FF finds the option selected
```

Comment: Try 'change' - `$('#formcategory').on('change','option',function() {` OR `$('#formcategory').change(function() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the cause of your problem, but I would not try to detect a `click` event on an `option` but instead the `change` event of the `select` itself:

```
$('#formcategory').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
}
```

An additional advantage is that it would allow keyboard selection as well.

Comment: I see. If I switch to the change event $(this) becomes the select element and I guess I would then have to grab the selected option?

Comment: @user2232681 Yes, that's what I am using `.val()` for.